# How to make Http Request to a php file present in plugin directory of wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, http-api

I'am new to wordpress plugin development and I'am developing a plugin (say myplugin) and I'am stuck in following problem.

I had kept this plugin in mywebsite/wp-content/plugin/myplugin

Inside myplugin directory i have 2 files as follows

1. myplugin.php
2. registration.php

Now i want to make http post request to above registration.php from mobile application. When i sent post request to http://mywebsite/wp-content/plugin/myplugin/registration.php it always says file not found. How can i make a request..

Is it a wrong way to do . If so can any one help me how to do it...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using standard login with registration allowed? Without seeing your code it is hard to determine the cause for your problem.

Comment: Iam creating a plugin which sends notification to all subscribed users when a new post is created. User can subscribe by making http post request to register.php. since i placed the registration.php inside plugin directory iam not able to access it from outstide.. How to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty plugin that shows you how to achieve this (adapt this example to your own architecture and needs):

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Custom rewrite rule test
*/

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded', 
    array(Registration::get_instance(), 'setup')
);

class Registration {

    protected static $instance = NULL;

    public function __construct() {}

    public static function get_instance() {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }    

    public function setup() {

        add_action('init', array($this, 'rewrite_rules'));
        add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'), 10, 1);
        add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'parse_request'), 10, 1);

        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'flush_rules' ));

    }

    public function rewrite_rules(){
        add_rewrite_rule('registration/?$', 'index.php?registration=true', 'top');
    }

    public function flush_rules(){
        $this->rewrite_rules();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    public function query_vars($vars){
        $vars[] = 'registration';
        return $vars;
    }

    public function parse_request($wp){
        if ( array_key_exists( 'registration', $wp->query_vars ) ){
            include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'registration.php';
            exit();
        }
    }

}
```

- register your custom rewrite rule "registration" using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
- add a custom query variable "registration"
- parse the request, check for "registration" query variable, if exists, include a `registration.php` file

The advantage of adding an **internal** WordPress rewrite rule isntead of an external one is that the WordPress environment will be available to you in your `registration.php` file, so for example if you need to modify or retrieve data from the database you can.

Example inside your `registration.php` file:

```
<?php 

global $wp, $wpdb;

//get query variable: index.php?registration=true
var_dump($wp->query_vars['registration']); //true

//check if user is logged in
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  //use $wpdb to get results from database etc
}

//do your registration business logic here etc
```

Comment: Which URL should i use to make a call

Comment: http://www.example.com/registration

Comment: i have installed wordpress in my pc. I installed it in a folder called fwp. When i make the following request http://127.0.0.1/fwp/registration it says The requested URL /fwp/registration.php was not found on this server

Comment: @Harish_N `registration`, not `registration.php`. You're using an internal rewrite to route the request, as you should not be loading php files directly.

Comment: @Harish_N Make sure the plugin file above is in the same directory as your `registration.php` file, if not, you need to edit the path in the `parse_request` callback method.

Comment: I made a call to http://127.0.0.1/fwp/index.php?registration and it worked

Comment: @Harish_N What does your permalink structure in your `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalink` page say? Is it set to the default structure? This is likely why you cannot access the same page via `127.0.0.1/fwp/registration` and are getting a 404. Trying setting a custom structure as **post name**, save, then retry the pretty URL.